# Mixing Ca(OH)2 with Ca(NO3)2

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph, stoichiometry

Mixing $\ce{Ca(OH)_2}$ with $\pu{0.1 M}$ concentration of $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$.

What will actually happen in the process? What I will see with my eyes? I know that $\ce{Ca^2+}$ cation with concentration of $\pu{0.1 M}$ will be the first to react with $\ce{OH-}$, am I right? Would there be any changes in color? What will be the timing to the end point (approximately) of the reaction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not much is going to happen. Due to low solubility of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$, further suppressed by the presence of calcium cations from the dissolved $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$, you get a suspension of calcium hydroxide, which unfiltered looks like white cloudy liquid and is also known as [milk of lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limewater).

---

Regarding the $\mathrm{pH}$ if the solution, $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$ is prone to hydrolysis and alone would create slightly acidic medium:

Step 1:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Ca(NO3)2 + H2O &<=> CaOHNO3 + HNO3} \tag{R1.1}\\
\ce{Ca^2+ + 2 NO3- + H2O &<=> CaOH+ + 2 NO3- + \color{red}{H+}}\tag{R1.2}\\
\ce{Ca^2+ + H2O &<=> CaOH+ + \color{red}{H+}}\tag{R1.3}
\end{align}
$$

Step 2:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CaOHNO3 + H2O &<=> Ca(OH)2 + HNO3}\tag{R2.1}\\
\ce{CaOH+ + NO3- + H2O &<=> Ca(OH)2 + NO3- + \color{red}{H+}}\tag{R2.2}\\
\ce{CaOH+ + H2O &<=> Ca(OH)2 + \color{red}{H+}}\tag{R2.3}
\end{align}
$$

(Here .1, .2, .3 stand for molecular, complete ionic, and net ionic equation, correspondingly.)

But, when you add enough $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ (saturated solution), which is a strong base:

$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 <=> Ca^2+ + 2 \color{blue}{OH-}}\, ,$$

I'd expect the resulting solution to be basic.